# Ubuntu OpenVPN is connected but won't change IP

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I know very little, just want a VPN so I can browse in privacy. So...

I downloaded the .ovpn file from CyberGhost, downloaded OpenVPN, put in the details and all that. At first it didn't connect to the internet at all but I changed the iptables and stuff like that (as forums suggested - I don't understand this stuff) and then it started working.

Now my issue is that my VPN doesn't change my IP at all.

Here's some data. I don't know much what this means. I just want my VPN to work :'(

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:d3:c1:65:df:a2  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:12524 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:12524 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1202759 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:1202759 (1.2 MB)

tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 62:22:d9:7f:3c:da  
      inet addr:10.129.9.170  Bcast:11.255.255.255  Mask:254.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::6022:d9ff:fe7f:3cda/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:59 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:8996 (8.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:5a:b6:81:4e:65  
      inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::4a5a:b6ff:fe81:4e65/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:219619 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:137619 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:266730368 (266.7 MB)  TX bytes:15699055 (15.6 MB)
```

Some kind of config.

```
client
remote 4-ro.cg-dialup.net 443
dev tun 
proto udp
auth-user-pass


resolv-retry infinite 
redirect-gateway def1
persist-key
persist-tun
nobind
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth MD5
ping 5
ping-exit 60
ping-timer-rem
explicit-exit-notify 2
script-security 2
remote-cert-tls server
route-delay 5
tun-mtu 1500 
fragment 1300
mssfix 1300
verb 4
comp-lzo


ca ca.crt

cert client.crt

key client.key
```

I also have 'use this connection only for resources on its network' ticked.

/sbin/route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref        Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
5.254.97.77     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         254.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 tap0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

This was all whilst the VPN was connected. Can you help explain to me in layman's terms what I need to do? I really need help.

Comment: Try the steps found on their website for Linux Mint - the steps should be the same for Ubuntu it includes pictures: https://support.cyberghostvpn.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/395/0/configure-openvpn-for-linux-mint-with-network-manager

Answer (score 1):

> I also have 'use this connection only for resources on its network' ticked.

This might be the problem. To use a connection only for it's ressources means, that you address only services inside this vpn through that vpn. If you connect to a website, which is apparently not inside this network, it is not a local ressource and will not be connected through the vpn.

Also your first route entry says

```
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
```

which means that all connections to outside go through your wlan0 interface. With a working vpn it would look like this (adapted to your case):

```
0.0.0.0         254.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         UG    0     0        0 tap0
```

I assume that you are using the network-manager to connect so I would recommend to untick 'use this connection only for resources on its network'.
Also if you're using the network-manager you usually don't need to change any iptables rules, only if you are using the openvpn service with the config file.

Answer (score 0):

A summary of the steps found on their website (please note the link contains pictures to help you and are very similar for Ubuntu - the difference really is just the way the GUI looks, e.g. network icon is on the top right for Ubuntu, and instead of a Windows-like start menu, we have the dash): https://support.cyberghostvpn.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/395/0/configure-openvpn-for-linux-mint-with-network-manager

1. Login to your account on the website.
2. Click on "My Devices".
3. Select "Other Devices" (with the penguin logo).
4. Pick the following options:

   1. Protocol: OpenVPN (TCP).
   2. Operating System: Linux.
   3. Country: Select any that you want.
   4. Server Group: Select any that you want.
5. Download the configuration files and extract the zip file.
6. Make sure you have the following installed `openvpn`, `bridge-utils`, `network-manager-openvpn` and `network-manager-openvpn-gnome`.

   1. You can do this by typing into a terminal: `sudo apt-get install openvpn bridge-utils network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome`.
7. Make sure you log out of the system and log back in, or alternatively type in `sudo restart network-manager`.
8. Rename .ovpn file you downloaded to the name you would like it to appear in your network manager.
9. Click on the network icon in the top-right bar, go down to `VPN Connections` and pick `Configure VPN...` - you can also access this from the dash and typing in `Network Connections`.
10. Click the `Add` button, and select `Import a saved VPN configuration...`.
11. Go to the folder of the files you previously downloaded and renamed, and select the .ovpn file.
12. Make sure you check the `VPN` tab that the settings are correct, I'll copy and paste the information provided on the site here for you:

    1. Connection name: Type in a name for this connection, ideally composed out of the country to surf from and maybe the server group to be used, e. g. 'CyberGhost RO NoSpy'.
    2. Gateway: The server address is already filled in by the loaded configuration file
    3. Type: Choose 'Password with certificates (TLS)' (usually already filled in by the loaded configuration file)
    4. User name: Your regular CyberGhost user name.
    5. Password: Your regular CyberGhost password.
    6. User certificate: Enter here the path to the user certification file ('client.crt') - usually already filled in by the loaded configuration file
    7. CA certificate: Enter here the path to the CA certification file ('ca.crt') - usually already filled in by the loaded configuration file
    8. Private Key: Enter here the path to the key file ('client.key') - usually already filled in by the loaded configuration file
13. Click save.

Now to use the new VPN, simply click on the network icon in the top-right bar and select the VPN connection you imported (or if you use the information below for the manual process, select the one you created).

**Note: If those steps don't work out for you change the steps 10, 11 and 12 to do the following:**

10. Click `Add` and pick `OpenVPN` instead of importing.
11. Click on `Create` and again I will copy and paste the information found on the website below which you need to put into the `VPN` tab:

    1. Connection name: Type in a name for this connection, ideally composed out of the country to surf from and maybe the server group to be used, e. g. 'CyberGhost RO NoSpy'
    2. Gateway: The server address you noted from your account management, e. g. '4-ro.cg-dialup.net'
    3. Type: Choose 'Password with certificates (TLS)'
    4. User name: Your regular CyberGhost user name.
    5. Password: Your regular CyberGhost password.
    6. User certificate: Enter here the path to the user certification file ('client.crt'). For that click on the symbol right handed and search for the respective file in your CyberGhost folder.
    7. CA certificate: Enter here the path to the CA certification file ('ca.crt'). For that click on the symbol right handed and search for the respective file in your CyberGhost folder.
    8. Private Key: Enter here the path to the key file ('client.key'). For that click on the symbol right handed and search for the respective file in your CyberGhost folder.
12. Click on the `Advanced` button and enter the following (from the website):

    1. Tab 'General':

       1. Use custom gateway port: 9081 (for TCP connections: 80)
       2. Use custom renegotiation interval: Deactivated (also for TCP connections)
       3. Use LZO data compression: Activated (also for TCP connections)
       4. Use a TCP connection: Only activated, if you have chosen an OpenVPN TCP connection while configuring your native VPN in your account management.
       5. Use a TAP device: Activated (if no data connections can be established, please deactivate; for TCP also deactivate)
       6. Use custome tunnel MTU: 1500 (for TCP please deactivate)
       7. Use custom UDP fragment size: 1300 (for TCP please deactivate)
       8. Restrict tunnel TCP Maximum Segment Size (MSS): Deactivated (also for TCP)
       9. Randomize remote hosts: Deactivated (also for TCP)
    2. Tab 'Security'

       1. Cipher: AES-256-CBC (also for TCP)
       2. HMAC Authentification: MD-5 (also for TCP)
13. Click on `OK` and then `Save`.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder where you downloaded that from?

https://support.cyberghostvpn.com/index.php?/CGVPN/Knowledgebase/Article/View/393/0/devices-that-support-cyberghost-vpn

I don't see the download there for linux?

Anyway I'm looking to install it as well, but got stuck real fast.

Comment: Just look at the right side of the page, saying "Alternatively to using CyberGhost VPN with its own client, a Premium user can connect directly via the OpenVPN, L2TP/IPSec or PPTP protocol with the CyberGhost VPN network." So you can use Linux and OpenVPN for example.